# How create a sequence of number with Excel starting with the letter "A"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[I need to create a sequence here the next should be A100100101000002 and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzuBo.png)

I try many ways, I am not experienced with Excel any help is highly appreciated. Thank all

Comment: If you compare this negative response to the positive response you received from your last question then you might realize that **showing original effort is expected**, even when it doesn't work.

Comment: This is way too broad - you can easily do like `="A1001001010000"&row()`What have you tried? What has/hasn't worked?

Comment: @BruceWayne thank you, I got it by creating a javascript function and just creating a web page that looks like Excel. Thanks again I am not an Excel user so I put it aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in A1,

```
=text(row(1:1), "\A\1\0\0\1\0\0\1\0\1000000")
```

Fill down. That should be good up to row 999,999.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I went and did it in a web form but this is great thank you so much.

Comment: Thinking about it, did you use `Text()`, because doing `="A"&10010010100"&row()` may "overflow", as when you get to the larger rows? And using `TEXT()` will keep it a uniform length, and "work its way left" as the rows increase?  [Neat!](http://i.imgur.com/iYOXpB3.jpg)

Comment: Using `="A"&10010010100"&row()` doesn't 'pad the leading zeroes' like you can with a format mask to keep uniform length.